# Calculating ISIN checksum

Tags: checksum

HI I know there have been may question about this here but I wasn't able to find a detailed enough answer, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number#Examples) has two examples of ISIN and how is their checksum calculated.

The part of calculation that I'm struggling with is

> Multiply the group containing the rightmost character

The way I understand this statement is:

- Iterate through each character from right to left
- once you stumble upon a character rather than digit record its position

  - if the position is an `even` number double all numeric values in `even` position
  - if the position is an `odd` number double all numeric values in `odd` position

My understanding has to be wrong because there are at least two problems:

- Every ISIN starts with two character country code so position of rightmost character is always the first character
- If you omit the first two characters then there is no explanation as to what to do with ISINs that are made up of all numbers (except for first two characters)

### Note

[isin.org](http://www.isin.org/education/) contains even less information on verifying ISINs, they even use the same example as Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you; the definition on Wikipedia is not the clearest I have seen.

There's a piece of text just before the two examples that explains when one or the other algorithm should be used:

> Since the NSIN element can be any alpha numeric sequence (9 characters), an odd number of letters will result in an even number of digits and an even number of letters will result in an odd number of digits. For an odd number of digits, the approach in the first example is used. For an even number of digits, the approach in the second example is used

The NSIN is identical to the ISIN, excluding the first two letters and the last digit; so if the ISIN is `US0378331005` the NSIN is `037833100`.
So, if you want to verify the checksum digit of `US0378331005`, you'll have to use the "first algorithm" because there are 9 digits in the NSIN. Conversely, if you want to check `AU0000XVGZA3` you're going to use the "second algorithm" because the NSIN contains 4 digits.

As to the "first" and "second" algorithms, they're identical, with the only exception that in the former you'll multiply by 2 the group of odd digits, whereas in the latter you'll multiply by 2 the group of even digits.

Now, the good news is, you can get away without this overcomplicated algorithm.

You can, instead:

1. Take the ISIN except the last digit (which you'll want to verify)
2. Convert all letters to numbers, so to obtain a list of digits
3. Reverse the list of digits
4. All the digits in an odd position are doubled and their digits summed again if the result is >= 10
5. All the digits in an even position are taken as they are
6. Sum all the digits, take the modulo, subtract the result from 0 and take the absolute value

The only tricky step is #4. Let's clarify it with a mini-example.
Suppose the digits in an odd position are `4, 0, 7`.

You'll double them and get: `8, 0, 14`.

8 is not >= 10, so we take it as it is. Ditto for 0. 14 *is* >= 10, so we sum its digits again: `1+4=5`.

The result of step #4 in this mini-example is, therefore: `8, 0, 5`.

A minimal, working implementation in Python could look like this:

```
import string
isin = 'US4581401001'

def digit_sum(n):
    return (n // 10) + (n % 10)

alphabet = {letter: value for (value, letter) in
            enumerate(''.join(str(n) for n in range(10)) + string.ascii_uppercase)}

isin_to_digits = ''.join(str(d) for d in (alphabet[v] for v in isin[:-1]))
isin_sum = 0
for (i, c) in enumerate(reversed(isin_to_digits), 1):
    if i % 2 == 1:
        isin_sum += digit_sum(2*int(c))
    else:
        isin_sum += int(c)

checksum_digit = abs(- isin_sum % 10)

assert int(isin[-1]) == checksum_digit
```

Or, more crammed, just for functional fun:

```
checksum_digit = abs( - sum(digit_sum(2*int(c)) if i % 2 == 1 else int(c)
    for (i, c) in enumerate(
    reversed(''.join(str(d) for d in (alphabet[v] for v in isin[:-1]))), 1)) % 10)
```

Comment: Have a hard time with US0358140123 listed in the ISIN database https://www.isin.net/isin-directory/, seems the algorithm delivers 9 (?)

Comment: @SamGinrich It looks like that specific ISIN is not valid even according to other online validators. See https://www.isincheck.com/?isin=US0358140123 for instance, or https://www.isindb.com/validate-isin/.

Comment: helpful link! US0358140129 is accepted, thx